# StaticInjectionError for matDialogRef

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, angular-material, frontend

I am working on a project with an angular frontend an trying to create a matDialogue, however I always get the error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CustomersComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CustomersComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
```

What I put in my html file does not matter, I get the error even if I leave it blank. 
Here is my ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html'
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  customerCreateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private custDialog: MatDialogRef<CustomersComponent>,
              private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: What is hte CustomersComponent, the component opening the dialog, or the component in the dialog ?

Comment: MatDialogRef is used for taking actions on an open dialog, such ad closing it. StaticInjectionError implies that there is no open dialog for CustomersComponent. If you share the code that opens the dialog or describe your exact use case it would be easier to spot the ptoblem.

Comment: Have you imported MatDialogRef in the module your CustomersComponent belongs to?

Comment: Please provide the stackblitz example!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am correct but as I can see in the error it is written No provides for MatDialogRef.

It is definitely because of import. Please check if you have imported the MatDialogModule in app.module.ts file.

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
@NgModule({ 
imports:[MatDialogModule] 
})
```